# Entire layout disappears when visibility state of certain views is altered from View.VISIBLE to View.GONE and back to View.VISIBLE

Tags: android, androidx

When View.VISIBLE is called at the end, the entire layout disappers.

This started happening after I upgraded my project to androidx. I am facing this issue on pre Nougat versions of android only.

I am changing visibility state of ContraintLayout with id "@+id/recyclerview_container"
and Button with id "@+id/done_button"

I have shared content of my XML file below.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.ts.marham_connect.fragments.extendedprofile.AreaOfInterestFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/zero"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/done_button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fifteen">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/areas_of_interest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/thirty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twenty"
            android:text="Areas of Interest"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_text"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_heading_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/thirty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten"
            android:text="Add areas of your interest to attract patients(Only 4)"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/areas_of_interest" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_your_interest_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/thirty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/thirty"
            android:text="Add New Interest"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/seventeen_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sub_heading_textview" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/specialities_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/thirty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_your_interest_text_view" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>


<MyButton
    android:id="@+id/done_button"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/confirm_button_height"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/thirty"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/thirty"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_body_green_button_circular_corners"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/vector_icon_arrow_right_white_2"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/fifteen"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/fifteen"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />


<include
    android:id="@+id/central_retry_button_container"
    layout="@layout/layout_central_retry_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<include
    android:id="@+id/central_progress_bar_container"
    layout="@layout/layout_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty"
    android:visibility="gone"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

```html
package com.ts.marham_connect.fragments.extendedprofile;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class AreaOfInterestFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener, ServerConnectListener, AdapterViewItemClickedListener {


    private ConstraintLayout recyclerViewContainer;
    private TextView addYourInterestTextView;
    private RecyclerView specialitiesRecyclerView;

    private View centralProgreeBar;
    private View centralRetryButton;

    private MyButton doneButton;

    private AlertWindow alertWindow;

    private SpecialitiesAdapter specialitiesAdapter;
    private List<Speciality> specialityList = new ArrayList<>();

    private FragmentInteractionListener fragmentInteractionListener;

    private Context context;


    public AreaOfInterestFragment() {
    }

    public static AreaOfInterestFragment newInstance() {
        return new AreaOfInterestFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_area_of_interest, container, false);
        initViews(view);
        setListeners();
        getSpecialities();
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.retry_button_container:
                getSpecialities();
                break;

            case R.id.add_your_interest_text_view:

                if (isSelectedListSizeWithInMaxSize(4)) {
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    alertWindow = new AlertWindow(context, getString(R.string.msg_when_user_tries_to_select_more_than_allowed));
                    alertWindow.show();
                }


                break;

            case R.id.done_button:
                if (isSelectedListSizeWithInValidRange(4)) {
                    submitSpecialitiesList();
                } else {
                    alertWindow = new AlertWindow(context, getString(R.string.msg_when_user_does_not_any_area_of_interest));
                    alertWindow.show();
                }
                break;

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onAdatviewItemClicked(int position) {


        if (specialityList.get(position).getChecked().equals("1")) {
            specialityList.get(position).setChecked("0");
            specialitiesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        } else {
            if (isSelectedListSizeWithInMaxSize(4)) {
                specialityList.get(position).setChecked("1");
                specialitiesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            } else {
                alertWindow = new AlertWindow(context, getString(R.string.msg_when_user_tries_to_select_more_than_allowed));
                alertWindow.show();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdatviewItemClicked(int position, int requestID) {
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
        recyclerViewContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_container);
        addYourInterestTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.add_your_interest_text_view);
        specialitiesRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.specialities_recyclerview);
        centralProgreeBar = view.findViewById(R.id.central_progress_bar_container);
        centralRetryButton = view.findViewById(R.id.central_retry_button_container);
        doneButton = view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        setUpSpecialitiesRecyclerView();
        setUpAlertDialog();

    }

    private void setListeners() {
        centralRetryButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        addYourInterestTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setFragmentInteractionListener(FragmentInteractionListener fragmentInteractionListener) {
        this.fragmentInteractionListener = fragmentInteractionListener;
    }

    private void setUpSpecialitiesRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        specialitiesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        specialitiesAdapter = new SpecialitiesAdapter(specialityList, this);
        specialitiesRecyclerView.setAdapter(specialitiesAdapter);
    }

    private void upDateProfileCompletionObject() {
        ProfileCompletion profileCompletion = (ProfileCompletion) SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().getSharedPreferenceObject(context, AppConstants.PROFILE_COMPLETION_OBJECT, ProfileCompletion.class);
        profileCompletion.setAreasOfInterest(context.getString(R.string.one));
        SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().setSharedPreferenceObject(context, AppConstants.PROFILE_COMPLETION_OBJECT, profileCompletion);
    }

    private void setViewsBeforeGettingSpecialities() {
        recyclerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        centralProgreeBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        centralRetryButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void setViewsAfterGettingSpecialities() {
        recyclerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        centralProgreeBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        centralRetryButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void setViewsIncaseOfInternetFailureOrUnExpectedResponseFromServer() {
        recyclerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        centralProgreeBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        centralRetryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    private void setViewsBeforeSubmittingSpecialities() {
        recyclerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        centralProgreeBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void setViewsAfterSubmittingSpecialities() {
        recyclerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        centralProgreeBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void setViewsIncaseOfInternetFailureOrUnExpectedResponseFromServerWhileSubmittingSpecialities() {
        recyclerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        centralProgreeBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    private boolean isSelectedListSizeWithInMaxSize(int minListSize) {
        int selectedItemCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < specialityList.size(); i++) {
            if (specialityList.get(i).getChecked().equals("1")) {
                selectedItemCount = selectedItemCount + 1;
            }

        }

        if (selectedItemCount <= minListSize) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }


    private boolean isSelectedListSizeWithInValidRange(int minListSize) {
        int selectedItemCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < specialityList.size(); i++) {
            if (specialityList.get(i).getChecked().equals("1")) {
                selectedItemCount = selectedItemCount + 1;
            }

        }

        if (selectedItemCount > 0 && selectedItemCount <= minListSize) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void getSpecialities() {
        setViewsBeforeGettingSpecialities();

        HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();
        info.put(getString(R.string.doctor_id_key), SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().getSharedPreferenceString(context, AppConstants.DOC_ID_KEY, null));
        info.put(getString(R.string.speciality_id_key), SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().getSharedPreferenceString(context, AppConstants.SPECIALITY_ID_KEY, null));
        info.put(getString(R.string.sub_speciality_id_key), SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().getSharedPreferenceString(context, AppConstants.SUB_SPECIALITY_ID_KEY, "0"));

        Call<GetSpecialitiesServerResponse> call = APIClient.getInstance().getApiService().getSpecialities(info);
        retroFit2Callback = new RetroFit2Callback<>(this, context, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_GET_SPECIALITIES);
        call.enqueue(retroFit2Callback);

    }

    private void submitSpecialitiesList() {
        setViewsBeforeSubmittingSpecialities();

        SpecialitiesListContainer specialitiesListContainer = new SpecialitiesListContainer();
        specialitiesListContainer.setdId(SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().getSharedPreferenceString(context, AppConstants.DOC_ID_KEY, null));
        specialitiesListContainer.setAreas(specialityList);

        Call<ServerResponse> call = APIClient.getInstance().getApiService().submitSpecialitiesList(specialitiesListContainer);
        retroFit2Callback = new RetroFit2Callback<>(this, context, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_SUBMIT_SPECIALITIES);
        call.enqueue(retroFit2Callback);

    }


    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ServerResponse response) {

        switch (response.getRequestCode()) {
            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_GET_SPECIALITIES:
                setViewsAfterGettingSpecialities();
                if (response.getReturn_status().equals(AppConstants.SUCCESS)) {
                    GetSpecialitiesServerResponse getSpecialitiesServerResponse = (GetSpecialitiesServerResponse) response;
                    specialityList.addAll(getSpecialitiesServerResponse.getData());
                    specialitiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    specialitiesRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                break;
            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_SUBMIT_SPECIALITIES:
                setViewsAfterSubmittingSpecialities();
                if (response.getReturn_status().equals(AppConstants.SUCCESS)) {
                    upDateProfileCompletionObject();
                    fragmentInteractionListener.onFramentRequest(AppConstants.FragmentInteractionRequest.CHANGE_PAGE);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(ServerResponse response) {
        Toast.makeText(context, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (response.getRequestCode()) {
            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_GET_SPECIALITIES:
                setViewsIncaseOfInternetFailureOrUnExpectedResponseFromServer();
                break;

            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_SUBMIT_SPECIALITIES:
                setViewsIncaseOfInternetFailureOrUnExpectedResponseFromServerWhileSubmittingSpecialities();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionExpiry(ServerResponse response) {
        Toast.makeText(context, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (response.getRequestCode()) {
            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_GET_SPECIALITIES:
                setViewsIncaseOfInternetFailureOrUnExpectedResponseFromServer();
                break;
            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_SUBMIT_SPECIALITIES:
                setViewsIncaseOfInternetFailureOrUnExpectedResponseFromServerWhileSubmittingSpecialities();
                break;
        }
    }

    // ADD SPECIALITY POP UP

    private Dialog dialog;
    private EditText specialityEditText;
    private MyButton addButton;
    private MyButton cancelButton;

    private void setUpAlertDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_window_add_speciality);
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_speciality_edittext);
        specialityEditText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_speciality_edittext);
        addButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        cancelButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.add_button:
                    if (validateUserEnteredData()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.cancel_button:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private boolean validateUserEnteredData() {
        boolean allFieldsValid = true;


        if (!Utils.getInstance().isEmpty(specialityEditText)) {
            if (specialityList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < specialityList.size(); i++) {
                    if (specialityList.get(i).getTitle().equals(specialityEditText.getText().toString())) {
                        allFieldsValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (allFieldsValid) {
                addNewSpeciality();
            }
        } else {
            specialityEditText.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_value));
            allFieldsValid = false;
        }
        return allFieldsValid;
    }

    private void addNewSpeciality() {
        Speciality speciality = new Speciality();
        speciality.title = specialityEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        speciality.setChecked(getString(R.string.one));
        speciality.setId("0");
        specialityList.add(0, speciality);
        specialitiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        specialityEditText.setText(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you changing the visibility of your root `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: no, I am changing visibility of Constrainlayout inside ScrollView with id "@+id/recyclerview_container"

Comment: Show your java code.

Comment: @Ankita I have added the java code.